# I3 WM bindsym giving error but in terminal, works fine

Tags: command-line, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, i3, picom

I have this in my i3 config to restart picom:
`bindsym $mod+Shift+P exec killall picom; sleep 0.2; picom`

It works fine in terminal but when I press the keybinding, it shows error, and it just says you have error in this line but don't tell which error.

Answer (score 1):

See https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec and, semicolons have special meaning in i3:

> See [command_chaining] for details on the special meaning of ; (semicolon) and , (comma): they chain commands together in i3, so you need to use quoted strings (as shown in [exec_quoting]) if they appear in your command.

and

> Commands can be chained by using ; (a semicolon)

so `bindsym $mod+Shift+P exec killall picom; sleep 0.2; picom` tries to bind $mod-shift-P to `exec killall picom`, followed by the i3 command `sleep 0.2`, followed by the i3 command `picom`. The latter two are not i3 commands.

I suggest moving `killall picom; sleep 0.2; picom` into a shell script and instead bind $mod-shift-P to that shell script with `bindsym $mod+Shift+P exec /path/to/script.sh`.